# How to reset spark structured streaming data to last available offset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am running a structured stream application with Kafka.  I found that if for some reason the system is down for days...  The checkpoint become stale and offsets corresponding to the checkpoint is not found in Kafka.  How do I let Spark Structured Streaming app pick the last available offset and start from there.   I tried setting offset reset to earlier/latest but the system was crashing with following error:

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetOutOfRangeException: Offsets out of range with no configured reset policy for partitions: {MyTopic-574=6559828}
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseCompletedFetch(Fetcher.java:970)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:490)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1259)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1187)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1115)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer.fetchData(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:470)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer.org$apache$spark$sql$kafka010$InternalKafkaConsumer$$fetchRecord(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:361)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer$$anonfun$get$1.apply(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:251)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer$$anonfun$get$1.apply(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:234)
at org.apache.spark.util.UninterruptibleThread.runUninterruptibly(UninterruptibleThread.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer.runUninterruptiblyIfPossible(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:209)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer.get(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:234)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaDataConsumer$class.get(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaDataConsumer$CachedKafkaDataConsumer.get(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:500)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchInputPartitionReader.next(KafkaMicroBatchReader.scala:357)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(DataSourceRDD.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.sort(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:216)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec$$anonfun$1.apply(SortExec.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec$$anonfun$1.apply(SortExec.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Can you show the code of your consumer together with your configurations? Also, which versions are you using?

Comment: I had same issue & I have followed this approach - As you mentioned offsets in your checkpoint is too old, can you please take backup & delete your checkpoint location & Try to start your spark application. That should work..

Comment: @Srinivas Thanks so much for your response.  We want to not touch the real time streaming pipeline... If offsets are old we want Spark to ignore the offsets and continue.  I have set failOnDataLoss to false but that did not solve my issue.  If above issue happen I have to clean the checkpoint i.e user data then restart Spark.  This is not acceptable for production system.

Answer (score 0):

If the system was down for days then it means that some logs might have been compacted. More precisely, your application attempts to read offset `6559828` from the 574th partition in topic `MyTopic`.

---

In order to find the earliest available offset per partition, you can simply run the following command:

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell \
    --broker-list localhost:9092 \
    --topic MyTopic \
    --time -2
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment.  I want structured streaming application to NOT stop... continue processing without with the last offset that is it can find.

Comment: @Alchemist You just need to `auto.offset.reset` to `latest`. The reason why the application got corrupted was because the log compaction took place and removed some of the messages and your streams application couldn't find where to start. Also consider to increase log compaction period in order to avoid this behaviour in the future.

Comment: Thanks @Giorgos Myrianthous... I have been struggling to tune this simple structured streaming application for a month... I had already set the auto.offset.reset equivalent to latest.  Do you have any list of tuning parameters that I need to absolutely consider while tuning the spark system that uses Kafka... I am using Kafka topic that has retention set to 3 days.  I cannot modify the topic.  Looks like this is topic level setting that impact other consumers of the topic.  But is there any recommended setting for Spark Structured Streaming with Kafka... I really appreciate your response.

Comment: @Alchemist I haven’t advised you to modify the topic and affect the other consumers. I was talking about your streams application.

Comment: Thanks I had already set auto.offset.reset to latest in spark using startingOffsets to latest.  But do not know how to set the log compaction period on Spark Structured Streaming consumer.

Comment: @Alchemist The compaction period is not set on the consumer side but on topic level instead. But again, I don’t know if you need more compaction period. But I would say you need to monitor your cluster and your clients more systematically. You must be able to know when your client (or maybe a broker) is down.